# Firebase function CORS preflight request very slow after inactivity

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors, firebase-app-check

I have an issue where the CORS preflight (OPTIONS) request for an intermittently-used Firebase function takes some *8 seconds* when the function hasn't been used recently. I'm using Firebase's App Check, so I don't have direct control over CORS config. The actual function execution time is normal, and subsequent preflight requests are processed quickly until the function becomes inactive again.

From a HAR file:

```
Request method: OPTIONS
Wait time: 7299 ms
```

I wouldn't expect the infrastructure handling CORS preflight requests to be subject to cold starts in the same way as my actual function execution. Is an 8-second delay for a preflight request a normal occurrence due to cold starts, or could there be another issue? Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're seeing a cold start, which happens when the Cloud Functions environment has to start a new instance to run your code.

If you want to reduce the chances of that, you can keep a minimum number of instances warm (at a cost).

See the documentation on [Configure minimum instances](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/min-instances) and [Reduce cold starts by setting a minimum number of instances](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#min)
.

Comment: I agree it sure seems like a cold start issue. Would cold starts affect the preflight cors requests though? I'd think they'd be handled by Cloud Functions infrastructure, not affected by the frequency my own functions are called.

Comment: Frank is the expert here but considering your function does go cold at some point, what's this other infra that you expect to be warm at all times for a cloud function? The function gets hit, it's cold, cors is checked etc.